# Problema identificacion en array

Tags: java, arraylist

Estaba realizando un método java al cual le paso una matricula de un camion. Este método, cuando encontrase un camión con esa matrícula, iba a apuntar su hora de llegada, e iba a marcar si había llegado a tiempo o no (esta última parte funciona, es meramente explicativa). El problema viene cuando utilizo este método, nunca encuentra el camión con la matricula indicada. Mi código del método es:

```
public void llegaCamion(String matricula) {
    LocalDate date=LocalDate.now();
    int dow=date.getDayOfWeek().ordinal();
    if(dow==0) {
        for(int i=0;i<planificadosMonday.size();i++) {
            if(planificadosMonday.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
                planificadosMonday.get(i).setHoraDesc(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hemos encontrado el camión");
    }else if(dow==1) {
        for(int i=0;i<planificadosTuesday.size();i++) {
            if(planificadosTuesday.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
                planificadosTuesday.get(i).setHoraDesc(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hemos encontrado el camión");
    }else if(dow==2) {
        for(int i=0;i<planificadosWednes.size();i++) {
            if(planificadosWednes.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
                planificadosWednes.get(i).setHoraDesc(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hemos encontrado el camión");
    }else if(dow==3) {
        for(int i=0;i<planificadosThurs.size();i++) {
            if(planificadosThurs.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
                planificadosThurs.get(i).setHoraDesc(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hemos encontrado el camión");
    }else if(dow==4) {
        for(int i=0;i<planificadosFri.size();i++) {
            if(planificadosFri.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
                planificadosFri.get(i).setHoraDesc(LocalTime.now());;
                System.out.println("El camion ha llegado");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hemos encontrado el camión");

    }else {
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no hay camiones asignados el fin de semana");
    }
}
```

Como se puede intuir, es un if anidado que dependiendo del día que sea mira en una lista u otra (los camiones ya están distribuidos por días correctamente en otros métodos, y las listas contienen todos los elementos que deben).
El caso, es que en mi main, ponga la matrícula que ponga, no encuentra el camión aunque esté en la lista.

Os paso mi código del main

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    LocalDate date=LocalDate.now();
    DayOfWeek dow=date.getDayOfWeek();
    ListaCamiones l=new ListaCamiones();
    if(dow.ordinal()==DayOfWeek.MONDAY.ordinal()) {
        l.getPlanif("M");
        l.muestraCamionesPlanif("M");
    }//SEGUIR CON LOS DEMAS DIAS
    else if(dow.ordinal()==DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.ordinal()) {
    l.getPlanif("T");
    l.muestraCamionesPlanif("T");
    }
    else if(dow.ordinal()==DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.ordinal()){
        l.getPlanif("W");
        l.muestraCamionesPlanif("W");

    }else if(dow.ordinal()==DayOfWeek.THURSDAY.ordinal()) {
        l.getPlanif("TH");
        l.muestraCamionesPlanif("TH");

    }else if(dow.ordinal()==DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.ordinal()) {
        l.getPlanif("F");
        l.muestraCamionesPlanif("F");

    }else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    ArrayList<Camion>cam=(ArrayList<Camion>) l.getPlanificadosFri();
    for(int i=0;i<cam.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(cam.get(i).getmatricula());
    }
    l.muestraCamionesPlanif("F");
    String matricula="opi1928";
    l.llegaCamion(matricula);

}
```

De hecho, en: 
`for(int i=0;i<cam.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(cam.get(i).getmatricula());
   }`

consigo ver las matrículas, pero después cuando uso el método llegaCamion() no la encuentra.

Comment: En Java la comparación de cadenas no se hace con `==`, sino con `equals`. Es muy probable que el problema esté ahí, todas estas comparaciones fallarán: `if(planificadosMonday.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {`, por tanto, debes escribirlas así todas: **`if( planificadosMonday.get(i).getmatricula().equals(matricula) ) {`**, por otra parte, veo un código demasiado repetitivo. Se podría optimizar usando algo así como arrays o estructuras de datos, pero ese sería ya otro tema.

Comment: Exactamente, me di cuenta en cuanto redacté la pregunta y me puse a repasar el código otra vez. Muchas gracias por la ayuda igualmente!

Comment: De todos modos, como te comento al final, usas un código demasiado repetitivo. Deberías considerar estructurar mejor los datos, algo así como un array donde buscar la información... si te parece mucho por ahora, al menos cambia los `if  elseif  else` por una estructura `switch... case` ganarías en claridad y te ahorrarías varias líneas de código.

Comment: Donde estas definiendo las variables "planificados.....", no veo que las pases como parámetros ni que las definas dentro del método

Comment: Bueno, una estructura switch o anidar los ifs no cambia demasiado (yo, por costumbre suelo usar if-elseif), aunque de hecho, creo que acaba siendo más eficiente el uso de los if, aunque sea menos amigable. Respecto a estructurar los datos, es un programa que he empezado a hacer ayer, y las fechas en programación (junto con hacer las interfaces) son lo peor. El problema es que tengo que tener separados todos esos datos obligatoriamente. A lo mejor con un Map se puede solucionar este problema. Lo tendré en cuenta, muchas gracias otra vez

Answer (score 1):

En Java el método para comparar dos cadenas es  [**`equals`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), no `==`, por tanto todas las comparaciones así fallarán:

```
if(planificadosTuesday.get(i).getmatricula()==matricula) {
```

Debes escribirlas de este modo:

```
if ( planificadosTuesday.get(i).getmatricula().equals(matricula) ) {
```

Ese es sin duda el motivo del error.

> **NOTA SOBRE OPTIMIZACIÓN:**
>
> Se aprecia en tu pregunta un código demasiado repetitivo. Considera
>   implementar una estructura más clara para estos casos, como puede ser
>   un bloque `switch ... case`, o puedes también implementar algo más
>   avanzado como estructuras de datos que guarden la información en pares
>   clave/valor, buscando en esas estructuras la información según la
>   clave. Así te quitarás de encima tantos `if ... elseif ... else` y
>   tendrás un código más entendible, más claro, más portable, más
>   flexible.